# What's a reasonable control setup for a controller in KSP?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I can bind this and that axis to whatever in *Kerbal Space Program* for sticking my rockets, but my binds always feel clumsy and inelegant.  Is there a good "standard setup" for using a controller (i.e. X360) in *KSP*; especially for the major controls?

Bonus points for a config file of some sort (are binds stored in a file?)

Comment: Get a 6 degrees of freedom pair of joysticks?  I have yet to find a consumer grade translation stick, though.

Answer (score 5):

I'm still working on getting my controller to work (driver issues), but here's a setup I found that makes perfect sense to use:

- Left stick Up/Down: Pitch
- Left stick Left/Right: Yaw
- Right stick Left/Right: Roll

This makes sure you can navigate the NavBall using the left stick.

The RCS controls:

- Right stick Up/Down: RCS Forward/Backward
- D-Pad controls: RCS Translate Up/Down/Left/Right

Docking will be done with the D-Pad + Right stick.

I have no idea which controller you're using, I'm using the PS button scheme to explain:

- Square (left button): RCS On/Off
- Triangle (upper button): SAS On/Off
- Cross (lower button): Stage advancement
- Circle (right button): Something you use a lot. Lights, Landing gear, map switch, pick your favorite :)

I've heard a lot about issues with the triggers not working in KSP, I suggest you try it out with your controller :)

I've still to test this myself, but it seems to be a reasonably sound control setup.

**UPDATE**

I Got it working last night, and I'm really happy with this controller setup! Using MotionInJoy, I was able to get all buttons working. I've kept the aforementioned layout, with some extras:

Additional layout:

- L1: Toggle precision steering
- R1: Cut all thrust
- L2/R2: Thrust down/up
- Select: Lights on/off
- Start: Landing gear
- Circle: I mapped it to switching between rocket/orbit view. Oce you've set up a proper viewing angle for both, you can use this button to easily get a peek at your trajectory when trying to get into orbit (or deorbiting).

Answer (score 3):

My setup:

[image: gamepad setup for KSP]

This has been carefully thought out and tested.

Some of the buttons are still free (at least in some of the modes); I have no solid suggestions for them.